# UnknownError when trying to sign code in Powershell

Tags: powershell, code-signing

I have created a certificate for code signing and its in *Cert:\LocalMachine\Root* but when I try to sign my program (*example.exe*) it gives me *unknownError*.

I have tried all of the solutions I could find on the internet, none of them work.

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "Certificate" -Type CodeSigningCert -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Then I opened up certificate manager and moved it into trusted root authorities

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath 'C:\programs\example.exe' -Certificate $cert
```

Error:

```
SignerCertificate                   Status                    Path
-----------------                   ------                    ----
                                    UnknownError              example.exe
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose the problem. What is the exact error message? The help for `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` states: "[...] adds an Authenticode signature to any file that supports Subject Interface Package (SIP)." Is that true for your `*.exe` file? Please update your question _directly_ (don't respond with a _comment_).

Answer (score 0):

Run in PS
GCI Cert:\LocalMachine\My -CodeSigningCert
   this will show if the code Signing Cert is usable ( should show thumbprints )

if it shows nothing move the Cert from Root* to LM\Personal
try again.... is the cert listed as usable.

try signing again.

Comment: What if the certificate is a file and not in the certificate store?